# Running a c# exe using a powershell batch file

Tags: c#, powershell, exe

Hey I've got a quick question for you guys. I have a c# console app that I built, and I need to create a Powershell batch file to run it. I am brand new to Powershell and have tried a few things that I have found online, but to no avail. If someone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more options:

1. & your.exe [argument list]
2. [Start-Process](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) command let
3. Using .NET [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class

The option 1 is usually the easiest onewhen you just want to call .exe which path & name you already now and you don't need anything special (for example to run it as different user etc.)

Use option 2 & 3 when option 1 is not satisfactory. The option 3 is the "hardest" to configure, but it gives you the maximum flexibility and control over creation and execution of the external process.

**Update** Added example of how to send parameters to exe. For the example I'm using the command prompt utility (cmd.exe) as it can be found on any Win OS) :

```
$pathToFile= Read-host "Path to file"
& cmd.exe /C "ECHO This command executed in cmd.exe: pathToFile was $pathToFile"
```

So in your case it can look like:

```
$pathToFile= Read-host "Path to file"
& myProgram.exe "$pathToFile"
```

and your Program class can look like:

```
class Program
{
    private static string pathToFile;

    static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        if (args.Any()) pathToFile = args[0];
        if (args.Length>1) {Console.Error.WriteLine("Too many parameters");
            return 1;
        }
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathToFile))
        {
            Console.Write("PathToFile is missing. Please provide PathToFile:");
            pathToFile = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        // And here you do something with PathToFile

    }

}
```